# Simplyscroll.js Speed not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplyscroll

I have created a simple scroller that's dynamically updating through AJAX, but the speed is not working. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getScroller.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        somePostData : 'value'    
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.scroller-container').html(data.srollercontent);
        (function($) {
            $(function() {
                $(".scroller-container ul").simplyScroll({
                    auto: false,
                    manualMode: 'loop',
                    speed: 10
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    },
});
```

The scroll speed is not changing even if I change it, except when the value (speed) is greater than `300`.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Also, note that the IIFE and document.ready handler are not needed in the `success` callback function.

Comment: Hi Rory, yes I checked it, there's no error in console...